# Remove an invalid reference from a collection in JADE

Tags: jade-platform

I have an invalid reference in a collection in JADE. The relationship is parent/child, and I have fixed the issue which caused it, however the invalid reference is still there (see the screenshot from the Object Inspector below).

[image: Object Inspector]

Is there a way to remove this reference from the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I'd use [Collection::rebuild](https://www.jadeworld.com/docs/jade-2016/Default.htm#resources/encyclosys1/collection_class/rebuild.htm) on the collection directly.

```
Manager.firstInstance().allEmployees.rebuild();
```

Alternatively, the Application or CollClass [repairCollection](https://www.jadeworld.com/docs/jade-2016/Default.htm#resources/encyclosys1/application_class/repaircollection.htm) methods are more efficient options for large collections.

The Application version starts a separate thread to fix the collection asynchronously.

```
app.repairCollection(Manager.firstInstance().allEmployees);
```

The CollClass version works synchronously, but just focuses on fixing invalid entries (without worrying about rebuilding the structure of the collection).

```
Collection.repairCollection(Manage.firstInstance().allEmployees);
```

Comment: You could also use the Jade Logical Certifier to fix all collections in your database that have bad data in them.